# Virtual screen on Windows like XVFB on Linux

Tags: multiple-monitors, emulation

For a good while I have been playing with the idea of having a virtual screen which is "attached" to my real screen but does not really exist.

The idea is that it should almost be like xvfb, the virtual X server which only runs as a framebuffer and isn't attached to a real graphics card and screen.

My use case here would be to have an application running on the fake screen that will be screen-recorded all the time. I don't want to see this application the whole time though.

The ideal thing would be if the software had a virtual screen viewer that, in fact, is just a small window that displays whatever is on that virtual screen.

Let me recap:

- Virtual monitor attached to the real one in desktop extension mode
- Capability of recording said screen
- Capability of looking at said screen through an application window

The only idea I'd have that would come remotely close is running a virtual machine which has this hidden screen that is recorded. Though I can't just pull windows into this screen then!

Comment: Would multiple desktops not fit the bill, e.g. "virtuawin"

Comment: @Tog Actually... I've never tested that... It shouldn't be one of those that just hide the windows... I'll test it..

Comment: @Tog No, it does not work. Virtuawin works by using a trick. It hides all windows that don't "belong" on the current desktop. This brought me to an idea: Sysinternals Desktops creates more than one session and lets them run concurrently. Though it seems I can only screen-record from ONE of those sessions. If a session is not visible, it seems to not be able to be screen recorded... I am trying around with this right now.

Comment: I got a fake solution: Force-recognized a screen on my graphics card, activated that.